# Switch specific colors in a TPathData

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi Rio with firemonkey. I generated a polygon form TBitmap that has transparent background and some text in black. I want to change the black color only to red color of the polygon and save the changes to the original Tbitmap?
I tried iteration through the points of the TPathData and change the individual pixels, but this process is time consuming.
Is there a faster way to do switch the colors of TPathData?
This is the procedure that uses iteration through TPathData points the change the color of the pixel.

```
procedure TForm1.ChangePathColor(Npath : TPathData; TopV : Integer; BotV : Integer);

    var
    Polygon: TPolygon;
    Color: TAlphaColor;
    MyBitmap : TBitmap;
    BMPD, MBMPD : TBitmapData;
    MyBitmapCopy: TBitmap;
    access : TMapAccess;
    h,v : integer;
begin
    Npath.FlattenToPolygon(Polygon,1);
    MyBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
    MyBitmap.Assign(Image1.Bitmap);
    MyBitmapCopy := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
    MyBitmapCopy.Assign(MyBitmap);
    try
        if (MyBitmap.Map(access, BMPD) and (MyBitmapCopy.Map(access,MBMPD))) then
        Begin
            Try
                for h := 1 to MyBitmap.Width do
                    for v := TopV to BotV do
                        begin
                            if image1.Canvas.PtInPath(pointf(h,v),Npath) then
                                begin
                                    Color := BMPD.GetPixel(h,v);
                                    if (TAlphaColorRec(Color).R < 50) then  MBMPD.SetPixel(h,v, TAlphaColors.Red);
                                end;
                        end;
            finally
                MyBitmap.Unmap(BMPD);
                MyBitmapCopy.Unmap(MBMPD);
            end;
        end;
        Image1.Bitmap := MyBitmapCopy;
    finally
        MyBitmapCopy.Free;
        MyBitmap.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Excuse my poor English for misunderstanding. I will explain my problem in pictures 
[The User choose a verse by click and the verse is sent to color transformation procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOqXp.png)

[This is option will highlight the verse and is very fast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7626Z.png)

[This option will change the color of the verse and is very slow using the ChangePathColor procedure that change pixel by pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac03N.png)

The whole new changed BitMap will be sent back the TImage.
I want to speed up the process for the colorizing option.

Comment: See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.Stroke. Try setting the color of `TStrokeBrush` before drawing the `TPathData`. If I misunderstood what you need, please provide a [mre]

Comment: I inserted the iteration procedure code. It takes inappropriate time in mobile devices.

Comment: You are right, that is not the right way to change the color of the path. What I meant in my previous comment is that you should change the color of the `Canvas.Stroke.Color` before you call `Canvas.DrawPath()`, or if you at runtime want to change the color, keep hold of the path data, and simply redraw it with a new color.

Comment: The TBitmap is ready-made PNG file. I want to change color of some text (not all text) that is already present in it.

Comment: let us say that the TBitmap is 800 x 1000 pixels. I am interested in a rectangular area rect(100,200, 500,600) that contains blacked color text that unknown for me and want to change to red colored text.

Comment: The TPathData is passed from another procedure as you can see in the declaration of the procedure TForm1.ChangePathColor(Npath : TPathData; TopV : Integer; BotV : Integer); This TPathData is used and color changes and TBitMap is updated

Comment: This code image1.Canvas.PtInPath(pointf(h,v),Npath) will determine if a specific pixel is part the TPathData. Then I determine if the pixel color is black so it will be changed

Comment: I removed most of my previous comments as they were partly based on misunderstanding of your goals. I still don't understand why you cannot simply (re-?)draw the `Npath` in red color instead of the timeconsuming pixel reading, color checking and manipulation. Maybe somebody will understand.